# Pass variables from HTML form -> ajax load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**What I am trying to do**

I have a HTML form which looks like this:
[input text field]
[submit button].
I want the output results to display in only a small part of the page (don't want to refresh the entire page after the button is clicked).

**What I have done so far**

I am using jquery load() as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchresults(id) {
$('#myStyle').load('displaysearchresults.php?id=' + id ; ?>);
}
</script>
```

Results will appear in a div which is exactly what I want:

```
<div id='myStyle'></div>
```

**The problem**

The script above works just fine (I used a variation of it elsewhere). But I have 2 problems:

1-How to call the load() script from the form. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="searchresults('1')">
```

2-If I am not able to call the load() script from the form, how do I pass what is into the input text field to the load() script so in the end it can be proceessed by the displaysearchresults.php file???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently its not working since you have a typo:

```
function searchresult(id) {
                   /^ no s
    $('#myStyle').load('displaysearchresults.php?id=' + id ; ?>);
}
```

Here:

```
action="searchresults('1')"> // this should be on the onsubmit
                    ^
```

Since you're intention is to submit the form without reloading, you could do something like:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'displaysearchresults.php',
        data: {id: 1},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#myStyle').html(response); // assuming the markup html is already done in PHP
        }
    });
});
```

Of course in the PHP side, just call it like a normal POST variable:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // other stuff you have to do
    // echo markup stuff
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ghost, Thanks a lot. I am trying to implement the code you suggested. Just so that I do it properly: (1) The first part of your script must be in the head section between <script type="text/javascript"> and </script> tags, right? (2) The output of displaysearchresults.php will appear on the same page between the <div id='myStyle'> and </div> tags, right? (3) What do you mean by html markup in php? Thanks again.

Comment: @Guillaume what i mean by html markup is that, PHP will create the html tags, sample: `mysqli_fetch_blah_blah( echo '<tr><td>resulthere</td><tr>'; )`. so that means your PHP returns a markup, because some also doesn't do that. instead they send a json.

Comment: @Guillaume 1) yes you could put that inside the head tags. 2) the PHP can also be on the this same php file or on a separate one, but thats not good, separate the php instead. 3) the explanation above

Comment: Hi Ghost, I separated the php file. For now it is just an echo "Hello";. I am expecting that to be displayed between the <div id='myStyle'> and </div> tags after I click the submit button. But it is just not happening. It is a simple script, I don't know what's wrong... I inserted the <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script> in the head section and the corresponding jquery file is there... I don't get it...

Comment: @Guillaume here, i've setup a demo for you, so that you could see how it works http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xjnlzg

Comment: Thanks a lot Ghost. I am testing it on my laptop. It seems to be working. I will modify the script a bit to call the separate php file. I should be able to do that myself. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Guillaume yes i've setup it that way since its an online demo and i cant use a separate php file, but thats just about the idea of it. anyway im glad this helped

Comment: Hi Ghost, I have modified a bit your script so that what the user enters in the textbox is passed to the ajax data variable (see final script in my answer below). Now the ajax script is running when the user click submit. But is there a way to also run this script when the page is accessed for the first time? I mean on load. I would think I have to call function(e) somewhere but I tried a few things and it is not working. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: yes there is a way to call ajax on load page, just create another ajax below the `$(document).ready({ `. just use the same ajax script that is bound on form submit

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have been able to do what I wanted to do, i.e., displaying search results in part of the page without reloading.

Actually it is not necessary to use the ajax load() function. You can do it with the script below:

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
<input type="submit" name="test" />
</form>
<div id="myStyle"></div>
<p>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from reloading
$.ajax({
url: 'displaysearchresults.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
data: {text:$('#textbox').val()},
success: function(response) {
$('#myStyle').html(response);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

So what is this doing:

It will "read" what the user entered in the textbox,

When the user click the "submit" button, it will put that into a POST variable and send it to "displaysearchresults.php" without reloading the page,

The search results will be displayed between the "mystyle" div.

Pretty nice.

Note for beginers: do not forget to copy the jquery file to your root folder otherwise ajax just won't work.